# HAproxy + Varnish Cache configuration

Tags: webserver, haproxy, varnish

need some help here.

I have HAProxy that's load balancing 2 servers.

HAProxy - 192.168.1.20:80

Server 1 - 192.168.1.18:80

Server 2 - 192.168.1.19:80

Now I would like to configure Varnish Cache to work with HAProxy.

In the default.vcl file of Varnish I setted up the IP and port of the HAProxy, but when I when I type `-curl -I 192.168.1.20` (IP of the HAProxy) I don't get a message from it.

Any idea where I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, nevermind, seems that I was doing it wrong.

Because of the ports that varnish listens to, ports of haproxy frontend had to be editted.
Changed the fronted port of haproxy to 8080 and the the ports in `/etc/default/varnish` and `/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service` to be 80.
Also eddited the `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` port to be 80.
Did I got it right?